# Exchange 2007 owa http is giving me 403 error rather than redirecting ever since certificate renewal

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, exchange, exchange-2007

Redirect has been working fine to when users connect to http://owa.company.com they get redirected to a log in page at https://owa.company.com/owa.  It's just using the redirect setting in IIS.  Then today I created a new ssl certificate and replaced the old one on this Exchange server.  Now, I can connect directly to https://owa.company.com/owa just fine and it shows it is using the new certificate, however if I go to http://owa.company.com then I get a 403 http error.

It does work if I go to https://owa.company.com, then it will still redirect to the /owa site, but if I use plain http, then I get the errror.

I'm stumped!!  I've tried unchecking the redirect setting, restarting IIS and re-enabling the redirect setting, which did no good.  Everything else I've found with googling either has no solution or just gives instructions for enabling the redirect setting.

Again: this was working fine until I renewed the ssl certificate.

Comment: As a workaround, I have disabled the "require ssl" rule on the default site, which then lets the redirect happen.

Answer (score 1):

Exchange likes to set "SSL Required" on the IIS Web Site, which will cause this error for HTTP.  Check the info under "For a Configuration in Which SSL is Required on the Default Web Site":

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998359(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: Those are the instructions I followed.  That is how it is setup.  It's almost like it is hitting the "require ssl" rule before it is hitting the "redirect" rule.